# ¿Cómo mandar una alerta por un item?

Tags: react-native

Este es mi código:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View, FlatList, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from "react-native";
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      dataSource: []
    };
  }

  _onPressButton() {
    Alert.alert("debe de ir aqui el nombre del item a presionar");
  }

  renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButton}>
          onPress={this._onPressButton}
           <Text style={ styles.nameStyle }> Name: {item.name} </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  };

  renderSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View style={{ height: 1, width: "100%", backgroundColor: "#d3d3d3" }} />
    );
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const url = "http://localhost/lol.json";
    fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        let dataSource = [];
        Object.values(responseJson).forEach(item => {
          dataSource = dataSource.concat(item);
        });
        this.setState({ dataSource: dataSource });
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={this.renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuestion es que quiero al hacer click en algun item ejemplo: vegueta, goku quiero que en el alert me aparezca el nombre que eh seleccionado, ya intente hacer esto _onPressButton(item.name) pero me marca un error ¿que puedo hacer? Quiero remplazar "debe de ir aqui el nombre del item a presionar" por el nombre en donde se haga click para ser mas claro

Comment: Esta pregunta esta duplicada de una tuya anterior. Por favor, elimina esta pregunta, y edita la anterior sacando las imagenes y escribiendo este codigo. mira [ask]

Comment: @gbianchi si me explique?

Comment: Hola @FranciscoNavarrete, por favor edita tu pregunta dando click al enlace de [edit] debajo de esta, agrega todos los detalles relevantes mencionados en los comentarios y el contexto que creas necesario para ayudarnos a reproducir el problema y que obtengas solución a tu problema

Comment: @KacosPro Listo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pasarle un parámetro a tu función `_onPressButton` puedes hacerlo de esta manera:

```
_onPressButton(name) {
  Alert.alert(name);
}

renderItem = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._onPressButton(item.name)}>
         <Text> Name: {item.name} </Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```

Hacemos esto: `onPress={() => this._onPressButton(item.name)}` para que la función no se ejecute inmediatamente y lo haga solo cuando presionamos el componente

Comment: Gracias me ah servido